# Best way to get the Network Cost on .Net Core 2.0

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-standard

Is there a way of finding out the Network cost on .Net Core 2.0? 
This is how I get the Network cost in my c++ code:

```
hr = pNetworkCostManager->GetCost(&dwCost, NULL);
if (hr == S_OK) {
    switch (dwCost) {
    case NLM_CONNECTION_COST_UNRESTRICTED:  
    case NLM_CONNECTION_COST_FIXED:         
    case NLM_CONNECTION_COST_VARIABLE:      
    case NLM_CONNECTION_COST_OVERDATALIMIT: 
    case NLM_CONNECTION_COST_CONGESTED:    
    case NLM_CONNECTION_COST_ROAMING:     
    case NLM_CONNECTION_COST_APPROACHINGDATALIMIT:
    case NLM_CONNECTION_COST_UNKNOWN:
    }
}
```

One thing that .Net Core (2.0) has is NetworkInterfaceType (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterfacetype?view=netcore-1.0)

Based on the NetworkInterfaceType I can see if it has wifi, network or mobile connection but that will not translate to a cost. 

 Is there any way finding out the Network cost on .Net Core 2.0?

Comment: In your C++ sample, where does the `pNetworkCostManager` come from?

Comment: @Gimly it is an https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448257(v=vs.85).aspx object

Comment: Are you trying to determine metered vs. unlimited usage (i.e. money)?  Or, are you trying to determine performance (speed  bits/sec) ?

Comment: @SqlSurfer Metered vs unlimited

Answer (score 3):

To call `GetCost` you will have to use the COM interface. If you need to make exactly this call, i.e. pass `NULL` instead of an IP address into `GetCost`, then you will have to define the COM interface on your own to satisfy your needs, e.g. like this:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[ComImport, Guid("DCB00C01-570F-4A9B-8D69-199FDBA5723B"), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class NetworkListManager : INetworkCostManager
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    public virtual extern void GetCost(out uint pCost, [In] IntPtr pDestIPAddr);
}


[ComImport, Guid("DCB00008-570F-4A9B-8D69-199FDBA5723B"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface INetworkCostManager
{
    void GetCost(out uint pCost, [In] IntPtr pDestIPAddr);
}
```

Then you can obtain the cost information like this:

```
new NetworkListManager().GetCost(out uint cost, IntPtr.Zero);
```

If you don't have the requirement of passing `NULL` into `GetCost` you can simply add a reference to the COM type library "Network List Manager 1.0 Type Library", set "Embed Interop Types" to `false` and [use those definitions](https://antonymale.co.uk/calling-icostmanager-getcost-from-csharp.html).